# Using SetPolicy with Azure and Windows IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, windows-10-iot-core

I'm calling this code from Windows IoT Core on RPi3 and getting this error. I'm trying to send a message to a blob in Azure. However, it only does it once and silently fails.

The Code:

```
s_deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(s_iotHubUri, new 
DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(s_myDeviceId, s_deviceKey), 
TransportType.Mqtt);
await s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

The Error:
microsoft azure devices client "I/O Error Occurred".

I was told that a using SetPolicy/ExponentialBackoff might work but I haven't been successful in implementing it. I'm calling it from a static class if that means anything.

I found a solution with a dynamic class, but I'd have to change the architecture of my app to use it.

https://azureiot.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/azure-iot-hub-device-sdk-retry-policy/

Comment: Which sdk version did you use? Is the latest version(1.19.0) installed via nuget?

Comment: I used the latest, version 1.1.9 pre ...

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you get the `s_deviceKey`? were you following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/iot-dps/how-to-legacy-device-symm-key?view=tfs-2013)? I can not reproduce the error. Did you configure a route for routing the message to blob?

Comment: I created an IoT Hub and then created an IoT Device in it. The s_deviceKey was generated when I created the primary key in the IoT Device.

Comment: I was working with C#, Not C.

Comment: Could you please share more code so that i can reproduce the problem?